# Export a just-imported modified variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to export a just-imported variable which I modify along the javascript file? My attempt is below:

```
import { foo } from "bar"

foo = 2

export foo;
```

I try the code above, but I receive the log as follows:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Comment: Do you want to re-export as a named or default export: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the [imported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) variable this way. Only the module that exported the variable can change its value.

---

> "you should use default export" - no, why should you?

After **Bergi**'s comment, I realized that I caused a misunderstanding because I left some points missing and I clarified a little.

```
// bar.js

const bar = ...

export { bar }
```

Re-export:

```
// foo.js   

export * from "./bar"; // doesn’t re-export default
// or
export * as myBar from "./bar"; // re-export with default
// or
export { bar } from "./bar";
// or
export { bar as myBar } from "./bar";
// ...
```

Or you can export without asterisks or curly brackets. (Before I edited, I wrote *you should use default export* in this line. This is where **Bergi** stepped in)

```
import { bar } from "bar"
export default bar;
```

If you read the documentation, you'll also see the different features of importing and exporting.

---

**I will follow your comments**

*I want to define it in a file*

```
// define.js

import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

export { router };
```

*modify it on another*

```
// modify.js

import { router } from "./define.js";

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ message: "Hello world" });
});

export { router };
```

*export to my app in some other file*

```
// app.js

import express from "express";
import { router } from "./modify.js";

const app = express();

app.use("/", router);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server listening");
});
```

Let's make a request via browser or terminal. I will prefer terminal here.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/
// {"message":"Hello world"}
```

We could do imports and exports differently (like **export default**, etc.). If you look at the documentation for this, you can do it with different variations.

Comment: In case foo is an object with further properties, we may want to alter some property for the sake of power, for example, `foo.goo = 2` or `foo.extend({'a': 1})`. Isn't it possible?

Comment: If it's an object, it's possible. You can change the value of the object property.

Comment: In special, I use a router from `express.Router()`. I want to define it in a file, modify it on another and export to my app in some other file.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope I understood what you want correctly.

Comment: "*you should use default export*" - no, why should you?

Comment: @Bergi If exported as `export { some }` from a file, importing `import { some }` from another file and want to export **directly** from the imported file without curly brackets, shouldn't it use `export default`?

Comment: @Bergi I wrote it according to the example in the question. It may not apply to other import/export cases. If I am wrong, I would be very happy if you correct me.

Comment: @kanvil OP only wrote that they want to export the variable. It's not clear whether they forgot the curly brackets or forgot the `default` keyword; but in general named exports are preferred.

Comment: @Bergi You're right. I just wanted to write about a few different features as well.

Comment: I think we all learned something here today. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the export:

```
import { foo } from "bar"

foo = 2

export { foo } // short for `export { foo as foo }`
```

However, that still won't get you far, since imported variables are not writable. `foo = 2` doesn't work, you're not allowed to modify the import. You might as well drop that and just write

```
const foo = 2;
export { foo as foo }
```

or

```
export const foo = 2;
```

for short.